# Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function with Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I try to make a carousel with [Owl Carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) but when I try to paginate with my mouse (drag), it generates this error :  `Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function`

My HTML:

```
<div class="anim-carousel">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <?php for($i = 0;$i<30;$i++): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/100/100/<?= rand(1, 6); ?>">
        </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
            items: 5,
        });
    });
</script>
```

The errors on my console:
[image: Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function with Owl Carousel]

Comment: The code you posted is not the source of the error. Get rid of the comment after that `5` but that won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an outdated version. Please use the latest develop: https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2#building. Unfortunately it'll take some time before the next beta release, currently I'm pretty busy.